# Is it possible to combine Common and GND on a DC/DC converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

There is an isolated DC / DC converter [TMR1222](https://www.tracopower.com/products/tmr2.pdf)

- 12VDC will come to the input,
  The outputs will be + 12VDC and -12VDC

When connecting with dual output, there is a "Common" contact

Tell me, is this the earth? If so, why was it not called GND?

Can I connect Common to GND?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Traco TMS 2 series are isolated converters, so "ground" on the input side is, well, isolated from "common" on the output side.  Another company may have called them "input return" and "output return".

Yes, you can tie them together.  The two sides will no longer be isolated (in which case you may want to see if you can use a non-isolated module that costs less), but the thing should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The COMMON pin on the output of the Dual Output Model is the common return to the supply for the +Vout and -Vout outputs. That would be intended to connect to the DC ground of circuits powered from the + and - Vout power supply rails.

Since the DC-DC converter is meant to be an isolated unit you may not want to connect the Common output to the input GND. You would defeat your isolation that way. There would be nothing to prevent you from connecting them if your system configuration has a common DC ground throughout and you had no need for the isolation.